# What does the suspend function mean in a Kotlin Coroutine?

Tags: kotlin, async-await, suspend, kotlin-coroutines

I'm reading Kotlin Coroutine and know that it is based on `suspend` function. But what does `suspend` mean?

**Can Coroutine or function get suspended?**

From https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html

> Basically, coroutines are computations that can be suspended without blocking a thread

I heard people often say "suspend function". But I think it is the coroutine that gets suspended because it is waiting for the function to get finished? "suspend" usually means "cease operation", in this case, the coroutine is idle.

Should we say the coroutine is suspended?

**Which coroutine gets suspended?**

From https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html

> To continue the analogy, await() can be a suspending function (hence also callable from within an async {} block) that suspends a coroutine until some computation is done and returns its result:

```
async { // Here I call it the outer async coroutine
    ...
    // Here I call computation the inner coroutine
    val result = computation.await()
    ...
}
```

It says "that suspends a coroutine until some computation is done", but coroutine is like a lightweight thread. So if the coroutine is suspended, how can the computation be done?

We see `await` is called on `computation`, so it might be `async` that returns `Deferred`, which means it can start another coroutine

```
fun computation(): Deferred<Boolean> {
    return async {
        true
    }
}
```

In the quote, it is mentioned  ***that suspends a coroutine***. Does it mean `suspend` the outer `async` coroutine, or `suspend` the inner `computation` coroutine?

Does `suspend` mean that while outer `async` coroutine is waiting (`await`) for the inner `computation` coroutine to finish, it (the outer `async` coroutine) idles (hence the name suspend) and returns thread to the thread pool, and when the child `computation` coroutine finishes, it (the outer `async` coroutine) wakes up, takes another thread from the pool and continues?

The reason I mention the thread is because of: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/coroutines-basic-jvm.html

> The thread is returned to the pool while the coroutine is waiting, and when the waiting is done, the coroutine resumes on a free thread in the pool

Comment: suggest studying [Basics Of Kotlin](https://androidacademic.blogspot.com/2023/03/android-kotlin-coroutines.html) where this is explained in detail

Answer (score 332):

**Suspending functions** are at the center of everything coroutines.
 A suspending function is simply a function that can be paused and resumed at a later time. They can execute a long running operation and wait for it to complete without blocking.

The syntax of a suspending function is similar to that of a regular function except for the addition of the `suspend` keyword. It can take a parameter and have a return type. However, suspending functions can only be invoked by another suspending function or within a coroutine.

```
suspend fun backgroundTask(param: Int): Int {
     // long running operation
}
```

Under the hood, suspend functions are converted by the compiler to another function without the suspend keyword, that takes an addition parameter of type `Continuation<T>`. The function above for example, will be converted by the compiler to this:

```
fun backgroundTask(param: Int, callback: Continuation<Int>): Int {
   // long running operation
}
```

`Continuation<T>` is an interface that contains two functions that are invoked to resume the coroutine with a return value or with an exception if an error had occurred while the function was suspended.

```
interface Continuation<in T> {
   val context: CoroutineContext
   fun resume(value: T)
   fun resumeWithException(exception: Throwable)
}
```

Comment: I wonder how is this function actually paused? They always say that `suspend fun` can be paused but how exactly?

Comment: @WindRider It just means that the current thread starts executing some other coroutine, and will come back to this one later.

Comment: I've figured out the "mysterious" mechanism. It can be easily unveiled with the help of Tools > Kotlin > Bytecode > Decompile btn. It shows how the so called "suspension point" is implemented - via Continuation and so on. Anyone can take a look for yourselves.

Comment: @buzaa Here's a [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrrUCSi72E8) from 2017 by Roman Elizarov that explains it at the bytecode level.

Comment: On which thread does "along running operation" run? On the same thread that calls the suspend function?

Comment: By this explanation it sounds like you could put anything inside `long running operation` and the thread will just pause the execution anywhere it sees fit. That doesn't sound accurate. Calling a blocking function from inside a suspend function will still block the thread it's running on. The suspend function will run, and if it finds another suspend function call, it will save its state, and free the thread for the next task in the call stack to be run. When that task is complete, the original function resumes. Anyway, that's just how I've understood it: https://youtu.be/BOHK_w09pVA?t=577

Comment: basically, in other languages it's "async" ... just another fancy name

Comment: @NextDeveloper "async" would imply asynchronous behaviour. With `suspend` functions the code still behaves synchronously from the point of view of the reader: a call to a suspend function has to complete before the next instruction is run. Calling an `async` function without await in JS returns a `Promise`, so it's actually asynchronous from the caller's point of view. The actual implementation is kinda irrelevant to the message that the naming wants to convey. See https://medium.com/@joffrey.bion/kotlins-suspend-functions-are-not-javascript-s-async-they-are-javascript-s-await-f95aae4b3fd9

Answer (score 134):

> But what does suspend mean?

Functions marked with the `suspend` keyword are transformed at compile time to be made asynchronous under the hood (in bytecode), even though they appear synchronous in the source code.

The best source to understand this transformation IMO is the talk ["Deep Dive into Coroutines"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrrUCSi72E8) by Roman Elizarov.

For example, this function:

```kotlin
class MyClass {
    suspend fun myFunction(arg: Int): String {
        delay(100)
        return "bob"
    }
}
```

is turned into (expressed in Java instead of actual JVM bytecode for simplicity):

```java
public final class MyClass {
    public final Object myFunction(int arg, @NotNull Continuation<? super String> $completion) {
        // body turned into a state machine, hidden for brevity
    }
}
```

This includes the following changes to the function:

- The return type is changed to Java's `Object` (the equivalent of Kotlin's `Any?` - a type containing all values), to allow returning a special `COROUTINE_SUSPENDED` token to represent when the coroutine is actually suspended
- It gets an additional `Continuation<X>` argument (where X is the former return type of the function that was declared in the code - in the example it's `String`). This continuation acts like a callback when resuming the suspend function.
- Its body is turned into a state machine (instead of literally using callbacks, for efficiency). This is done by breaking down the body of the function into parts around so called *suspension points*, and turning those parts into the branches of a big switch. The state about the local variables and where we are in the switch is stored inside the `Continuation` object.

This is a very quick way to describe it, but you can see it happen with more details and with examples in the talk. This whole transformation is basically how the "suspend/resume" mechanism is implemented under the hood.

> Coroutine or function gets suspended?

At a high level, we say that calling a suspend**ing** function suspend**s** the coroutine, meaning the current thread can start executing another coroutine. So, the *coroutine* is said to be suspended rather than the function.

In fact, call sites of suspending functions are called "suspension points" for this reason.

> Which coroutine gets suspended?

Let's look at your code and break down what happens (the numbering follows the execution timeline):

```kotlin
// 1. this call starts a new coroutine (let's call it C1).
//    If there were code after it, it would be executed concurrently with
//    the body of this async
async {
    ...
    // 2. this is a regular function call, so we go to computation()'s body
    val deferred = computation()
    // 4. we're back from the call to computation, about to call await()
    //    Because await() is suspendING, it suspends coroutine C1.
    //    This means that if we had a single thread in our dispatcher, 
    //    it would now be free to go execute C2. With multiple threads,
    //    C2 may have already started executing. In any case we wait 
    //    here for C2 to complete.
    // 7. once C2 completes, C1 is resumed with the result `true` of C2's async
    val result = deferred.await() 
    ...
    // 8. C1 can now keep going in the current thread until it gets 
    //    suspended again (or not)
}

fun computation(): Deferred<Boolean> {
    // 3. this async call starts a second coroutine (C2). Depending on the 
    //    dispatcher you're using, you may have one or more threads.
    // 3.a. If you have multiple threads, the block of this async could be
    //      executed in parallel of C1 in another thread
    // 3.b. If you have only one thread, the block is sort of "queued" but 
    //      not executed right away (as in an event loop)
    //
    //    In both cases, we say that this block executes "concurrently"
    //    with C1, and computation() immediately returns the Deferred
    //    instance to its caller (unless a special dispatcher or 
    //    coroutine start argument is used, but let's keep it simple).
    return async {
        // 5. this may now be executed
        true
        // 6. C2 is now completed, so the thread can go back to executing 
        //    another coroutine (e.g. C1 here)
    }
}
```

The outer `async` starts a coroutine. When it calls `computation()`, the inner `async` starts a second coroutine. Then, the call to `await()` suspends the execution of the *outer* `async` coroutine, until the execution of the *inner* `async`'s coroutine is over.

You can even see that with a single thread: the thread will execute the outer `async`'s beginning, then call `computation()` and reach the inner `async`. At this point, the body of the inner async is skipped, and the thread continues executing the outer `async` until it reaches `await()`.
`await()` is a "suspension point", because `await` is a suspending function.
This means that the outer coroutine is suspended, and thus the thread starts executing the inner one. When it is done, it comes back to execute the end of the outer `async`.

> Does suspend mean that while outer async coroutine is waiting (await) for the inner computation coroutine to finish, it (the outer async coroutine) idles (hence the name suspend) and returns thread to the thread pool, and when the child computation coroutine finishes, it (the outer async coroutine) wakes up, takes another thread from the pool and continues?

Yes, precisely.

The way this is actually achieved is by turning every suspending function into a state machine, where each "state" corresponds to a suspension point inside this suspend function. Under the hood, the function can be called multiple times, with the information about which suspension point it should start executing from (you should really watch the video I linked for more info about that).

Comment: Great answer, I miss that kind of really basic explanation when  it comes to coroutines.

Comment: Why is not that implemented in any other language? Or am I missing something? I am thinking about that solution for so long, glad Kotlin has it, but not sure why TS or Rust have something like that

Comment: @PEZO well coroutines have been around for a long time. Kotlin didn't invent them, but the syntax and library make them shine. Go has goroutines, JavaScript and TypeScript have promises. The only difference is in the details of syntax to use them. I find it quite annoying/disturbing for JS's `async` functions to be marked this way and yet still return a Promise.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was not clear. I am referring to the suspend keyword. It is not the same as async.

Comment: Good explanation. my understanding is -  In the case of multithreaded/multicore machine, Coroutines may run in parallel on other thread or concurrently on the same thread and dispatching point would be the line calling the suspending function and the suspending point would be the line of await(). Is my understanding correct @Joffrey? and and any idea on how it decides to start another thread or continue on the same thread and whats the cost of new threads and how it optimized to reduce the context switching for a code with a lot of long running coroutines?

Comment: @Siva S Correct. The way coroutines are dispatched between threads is decided by the coroutine dispatcher, which can be customized. The dispatcher is one element of the Coroutine context, so you can switch to a different dispatcher at any point using `withContext`. You can also pass a dispatcher when calling coroutine builders such as `launch` or `async`. On the JVM, common dispatchers are `Dispatchers.Default` and `Dispatchers.IO` (look them up to learn how they behave). You can also create a custom dispatcher, for instance by creating an ExecutorService and calling `asDispatcher()`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It directly answers the two questions from the original post.

Comment: """In fact, call sites of suspending functions are called "suspension points" for this reason""" - Not sure if it's correct. Create a suspend function A that simply calls another suspend function B in an endless loop. The function B does not do anything suspending, juest does a println() for instance. Now if you cancel a coroutine that currently runs function A, the endless loop will not stop. It will continue indefinitely. From which I conclude that the coroutine never reaches a suspending point which means a suspend function call site (A->B) is NOT a suspension point.

Comment: @GenaBatsyan Not all suspend functions are cancellable, so this test doesn't show that there is no suspension point, but rather that a suspend function with just a print statement is not cancellable. I tried decompiling the code you described, and the function A does have a state machine with a suspension point for the call to function B.

Comment: That being said, I'm surprised because I would have expected the call to function B to throw `CancellationException` when resuming.

Comment: After further investigation, let me clarify. To be more accurate, there is a suspension point in function A in the sense that the function is broken down into parts before and after the call, driven by a state machine, and can handle the `COROUTINE_SUSPENDED` value. BUT, this specific function B never *actually* suspends (it never returns `COROUTINE_SUSPENDED`), so the function A never suspends either (because it would need to receive that value), so the dispatcher never has the opportunity to stop executing the coroutine at that point.

Answer (score 52):

To understand what exactly it means to suspend a coroutine, I suggest you go through this code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers.Unconfined
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
import kotlin.coroutines.resume
import kotlin.coroutines.suspendCoroutine

var continuation: Continuation<Int>? = null

fun main() {
    GlobalScope.launch(Unconfined) {
        val a = a()
        println("Result is $a")
    }
    10.downTo(0).forEach {
        continuation!!.resume(it)
    }
}

suspend fun a(): Int {
    return b()
}

suspend fun b(): Int {
    while (true) {
        val i = suspendCoroutine<Int> { cont -> continuation = cont }
        if (i == 0) {
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

The `Unconfined` coroutine dispatcher eliminates the magic of *coroutine dispatching* and allows us to focus directly on bare coroutines.

The code inside the `launch` block starts executing right away on the current thread, as a part of the `launch` call. What happens is as follows:

1. Evaluate `val a = a()`
2. This chains to `b()`, reaching `suspendCoroutine`.
3. Function `b()` executes the block passed to `suspendCoroutine` and then returns a special `COROUTINE_SUSPENDED` value. This value is not observable through the Kotlin programming model, but that's what the compiled Java method does.
4. Function `a()`, seeing this return value, itself also returns it.
5. The `launch` block does the same and control now returns to the line after the `launch` invocation: `10.downTo(0)...`

Note that, at this point, you have the same effect as if the code inside the `launch` block and your `fun main` code are executing concurrently. It just happens that all this is happening on a single native thread so the `launch` block is "suspended".

Now, inside the `forEach` looping code, the program reads the `continuation` that the `b()` function wrote and `resumes` it with the value of `10`. `resume()` is implemented in such a way that it will be as if the `suspendCoroutine` call returned with the value you passed in. So you suddenly find yourself in the middle of executing `b()`. The value you passed to `resume()` gets assigned to `i` and checked against `0`. If it's not zero, the `while (true)` loop goes on inside `b()`, again reaching `suspendCoroutine`, at which point your `resume()` call returns, and now you go through another looping step in `forEach()`. This goes on until finally you resume with `0`, then the `println` statement runs and the program completes.

The above analysis should give you the important intuition that "suspending a coroutine" means returning the control back to the innermost `launch` invocation (or, more generally, *coroutine builder*). If a coroutine suspends again after resuming, the `resume()` call ends and control returns to the caller of `resume()`.

The presence of a coroutine dispatcher makes this reasoning less clear-cut because most of them immediately submit your code to another thread. In that case the above story happens in that other thread, and the coroutine dispatcher also manages the `continuation` object so it can resume it when the return value is available.

Comment: Dispatchers other than the unconfined one are basically returning immediately from resume(), pretty much.

Comment: Very good example and explanation!

Answer (score 43):

As many good answers are already there, I would like to post a simpler example for others.

> **runBlocking** use case :

- myMethod() is `suspend` function
- `runBlocking { }` starts a Coroutine in blocking way. It is similar to how we were blocking normal threads with `Thread` class and notifying blocked threads after certain events.
- `runBlocking { }` does **block** the current executing thread, until the coroutine (body between `{}`) gets completed

  ```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
      Log.i(TAG,"Outer code started on Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().name);
      runBlocking {
          Log.d(TAG,"Inner code started  on Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().name + " making outer code suspend");
          myMethod();
      }
      Log.i(TAG,"Outer code resumed on Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().name);
  }

  private suspend fun myMethod() {
      withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
      for(i in 1..5) {
          Log.d(TAG,"Inner code i : $i on Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().name);
      }
  }
  ```

This outputs :

```
I/TAG: Outer code started on Thread : main
D/TAG: Inner code started  on Thread : main making outer code suspend
// ---- main thread blocked here, it will wait until coroutine gets completed ----
D/TAG: Inner code i : 1 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
D/TAG: Inner code i : 2 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
D/TAG: Inner code i : 3 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
D/TAG: Inner code i : 4 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
D/TAG: Inner code i : 5 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
// ---- main thread resumes as coroutine is completed ----
I/TAG: Outer code resumed on Thread : main
```

> **launch** use case :

- `launch { }` starts a coroutine concurrently.
- This means that when we specify launch, a coroutine starts execution on `worker` thread.
- The `worker` thread and outer thread (from which we called `launch { }`) both runs concurrently. Internally, JVM may perform **Preemptive Threading**
- When we require multiple tasks to run in parallel, we can use this. There are `scopes` which specify lifetime of coroutine. If we specify `GlobalScope`, the coroutine will work until application lifetime ends.

  ```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
      Log.i(TAG,"Outer code started on Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().name);

      GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
          Log.d(TAG,"Inner code started  on Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().name + " making outer code suspend");
          myMethod();
      }
      Log.i(TAG,"Outer code resumed on Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().name);
  }

  private suspend fun myMethod() {
      withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
          for(i in 1..5) {
              Log.d(TAG,"Inner code i : $i on Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().name);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

This Outputs :

```
10806-10806/com.example.viewmodelapp I/TAG: Outer code started on Thread : main
10806-10806/com.example.viewmodelapp I/TAG: Outer code resumed on Thread : main
// ---- In this example, main had only 2 lines to execute. So, worker thread logs start only after main thread logs complete
// ---- In some cases, where main has more work to do, the worker thread logs get overlap with main thread logs
10806-10858/com.example.viewmodelapp D/TAG: Inner code started  on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 making outer code suspend
10806-10858/com.example.viewmodelapp D/TAG: Inner code i : 1 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
10806-10858/com.example.viewmodelapp D/TAG: Inner code i : 2 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
10806-10858/com.example.viewmodelapp D/TAG: Inner code i : 3 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
10806-10858/com.example.viewmodelapp D/TAG: Inner code i : 4 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
10806-10858/com.example.viewmodelapp D/TAG: Inner code i : 5 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
```

> **async** and **await** use case :

- When we have multiple tasks to do **and** they depend on other's completion, `async` and `await` would help.
- For example, in below code, there are `2` suspend functions myMethod() and myMethod2(). `myMethod2()` should get executed only after full completion of `myMethod()` **OR** `myMethod2()` depends on result of `myMethod()`, we can use `async` and `await`
- `async` starts a coroutine in parallel similar to `launch`. But, it provides a way to wait for one coroutine before starting another coroutine in parallel.
- That way is `await()`. `async` returns an instance of `Deffered<T>`. `T` would be `Unit` for default. When we need to wait for any `async`'s completion, we need to call `.await()` on `Deffered<T>` instance of that `async`. Like in below example, we called `innerAsync.await()` which implies that the execution would get suspended until `innerAsync` gets completed. We can observe the same in output. The `innerAsync` gets completed first, which calls `myMethod()`. And then next `async` `innerAsync2` starts, which calls `myMethod2()`

  ```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
      Log.i(TAG,"Outer code started on Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().name);

       job = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
           innerAsync = async {
               Log.d(TAG, "Inner code started  on Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().name + " making outer code suspend");
               myMethod();
           }
           innerAsync.await()

           innerAsync2 = async {
               Log.w(TAG, "Inner code started  on Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().name + " making outer code suspend");
               myMethod2();
           }
      }

      Log.i(TAG,"Outer code resumed on Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().name);
      }

  private suspend fun myMethod() {
      withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
          for(i in 1..5) {
              Log.d(TAG,"Inner code i : $i on Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().name);
          }
      }
  }

  private suspend fun myMethod2() {
      withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
          for(i in 1..10) {
              Log.w(TAG,"Inner code i : $i on Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().name);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

This outputs :

```
11814-11814/? I/TAG: Outer code started on Thread : main
11814-11814/? I/TAG: Outer code resumed on Thread : main
11814-11845/? D/TAG: Inner code started  on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 making outer code suspend
11814-11845/? D/TAG: Inner code i : 1 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
11814-11845/? D/TAG: Inner code i : 2 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
11814-11845/? D/TAG: Inner code i : 3 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
11814-11845/? D/TAG: Inner code i : 4 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
11814-11845/? D/TAG: Inner code i : 5 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
// ---- Due to await() call, innerAsync2 will start only after innerAsync gets completed
11814-11848/? W/TAG: Inner code started  on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-4 making outer code suspend
11814-11848/? W/TAG: Inner code i : 1 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-4
11814-11848/? W/TAG: Inner code i : 2 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-4
11814-11848/? W/TAG: Inner code i : 3 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-4
11814-11848/? W/TAG: Inner code i : 4 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-4
11814-11848/? W/TAG: Inner code i : 5 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-4
11814-11848/? W/TAG: Inner code i : 6 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-4
11814-11848/? W/TAG: Inner code i : 7 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-4
11814-11848/? W/TAG: Inner code i : 8 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-4
11814-11848/? W/TAG: Inner code i : 9 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-4
11814-11848/? W/TAG: Inner code i : 10 on Thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-4
```

Comment: Thanks for describing the use cases.

Comment: This is the most comprehensive and simple example to make someone new understand how coroutines and play of threads work! Thanks Kushal!

Answer (score 15):

I wanted to give you a simple example of the concept of continuation. This is what a suspend function does, it can freeze/suspend and then it continues/resumes. Stop thinking of coroutine in terms of threads and Semaphore. Think of it in terms of continuation and even callback hooks.

To be clear, a coroutine can be paused by using a `suspend` function.  lets investigate this:

In android we could do this for example :

```
var TAG = "myTAG:"
        fun myMethod() { // function A in image
            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
                for (i in 10..15) {
                    if (i == 10) { //on first iteration, we will completely FREEZE this coroutine (just for loop here gets 'suspended`)
                        println("$TAG im a tired coroutine - let someone else print the numbers async. i'll suspend until your done")
                        freezePleaseIAmDoingHeavyWork()
                    } else
                        println("$TAG $i")
                    }
            }

            //this area is not suspended, you can continue doing work
        }


        suspend fun freezePleaseIAmDoingHeavyWork() { // function B in image
            withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                async {
                    //pretend this is a big network call
                    for (i in 1..10) {
                        println("$TAG $i")
                        delay(1_000)//delay pauses coroutine, NOT the thread. use  Thread.sleep if you want to pause a thread. 
                    }
                    println("$TAG phwww finished printing those numbers async now im tired, thank you for freezing, you may resume")
                }
            }
        }
```

Above code prints the following :

```
I: myTAG: my coroutine is frozen but i can carry on to do other things

I: myTAG: im a tired coroutine - let someone else print the numbers async. i'll suspend until your done

I: myTAG: 1
I: myTAG: 2
I: myTAG: 3
I: myTAG: 4
I: myTAG: 5
I: myTAG: 6
I: myTAG: 7
I: myTAG: 8
I: myTAG: 9
I: myTAG: 10

I: myTAG: phwww finished printing those numbers async now im tired, thank you for freezing, you may resume

I: myTAG: 11
I: myTAG: 12
I: myTAG: 13
I: myTAG: 14
I: myTAG: 15
```

imagine it working like this:

[image]

So the current function you launched from does not stop, just a coroutine would suspend while it continues. The thread is not paused by running a suspend function.

I think [this site can help](https://medium.com/@elye.project/understanding-suspend-function-of-coroutines-de26b070c5ed) you straight things out and is my reference.

Let's do something cool and freeze our suspend function in the middle of an iteration. We will resume it later in `onResume`

Store a variable called `continuation` and we'll load it with the coroutines continuation object for us :

```
var continuation: CancellableContinuation<String>? = null

suspend fun freezeHere() = suspendCancellableCoroutine<String> {
            continuation = it
        }

 fun unFreeze() {
            continuation?.resume("im resuming") {}
        }
```

Now, let's return to our suspended function and make it freeze in middle of iteration :

```
 suspend fun freezePleaseIAmDoingHeavyWork() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            async {
                //pretend this is a big network call
                for (i in 1..10) {
                    println("$TAG $i")
                    delay(1_000)
                    if(i == 3)
                        freezeHere() //dead pause, do not go any further
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then somewhere else like in onResume (for example):

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        unFreeze()
    }
```

And the loop will continue. Its pretty neat to know we can freeze a suspend function at any point and resume it after some time has beeb passed. You can also look into [channels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/channels.html)

Answer (score 12):

I've found that the best way to understand `suspend` is to make an analogy between `this` keyword and `coroutineContext` property.

Kotlin functions can be declared as local or global. Local functions magically have access to `this` keyword while global don't.

Kotlin functions can be declared as `suspend` or blocking. `suspend` functions magically have access to `coroutineContext` property while blocking functions don't.

The thing is: `coroutineContext` property
[is declared like a "normal" property](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/coroutines/Continuation.kt#L154) in Kotlin stdlib but this declaration is just a stub for documentation/navigation purposes. In fact `coroutineContext` is [builtin intrinsic property](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17609#focus=streamItem-27-2262995.0-0) that means under the hood compiler magic aware of this property like it aware of language keywords.

What `this` keyword does for local functions is what `coroutineContext` property does for `suspend` functions: it gives access to current context of execution.

**So, you need `suspend` to get an access to `coroutineContext` property - the instance of currently executed coroutine context**

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of great answers here, but I think there are two additional things that are important to note.

launch  / withContext / runBlocking and a lot of other things in the examples are from the coroutines library. which actually have nothing to do with suspend. you don't need the coroutines library to use coroutines. Coroutines are a compiler "trick". Yes, the library sure makes things easier, but the compiler is doing the magic of suspending & resuming things.

The second thing, is the compiler is just taking code that looks procedural and turning it into callbacks under the hood.

Take the following minimal coroutine that suspends that does not use the coroutine library :

```
lateinit var context: Continuation<Unit>

    suspend {
        val extra="extra"
        println("before suspend $extra")
        suspendCoroutine<Unit> { context = it }
        println("after suspend $extra")
    }.startCoroutine(
        object : Continuation<Unit> {
            override val context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext
            // called when a coroutine ends. do nothing.
            override fun resumeWith(result: Result<Unit>) {
                result.onFailure { ex : Throwable -> throw ex }
            }
        }
    )

    println("kick it")
    context.resume(Unit)
```

I think an important way to understand it is to look at what the compiler does with this code. effectively it creates a class for the lambda. it creates a property in the class for the "extra" string, then it creates two function, one that prints the "before" and another the prints the "after".

Effectively the compiler took what looks like procedural code and turned it into callbacks.

So what does the `suspend` keyword do? It tell the compiler how far back to look for context that the generated callbacks will need. The compiler needs to know which variables are used in which "callbacks", and the suspend keyword helps it. In this example the "extra" variable is used both before and after the suspend. So it needs to be pulled out to a property of the class containing the callbacks the compiler makes.

It also tells the compiler that this is the "beginning" of state and to prepare to split up the following code into callbacks. The `startCoroutine` only exists on suspend lambda.

The actual Java code generated by the Kotlin compiler is here. It's a switch statement instead of callbacks, but it's effectively the same thing. Called first w/ case 0, then w/ case 1 after the resume.

```
            @Nullable
            public final Object invokeSuspend(@NotNull Object $result) {
                var10_2 = IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED();
                switch (this.label) {
                    case 0: {
                        ResultKt.throwOnFailure((Object)$result);
                        extra = "extra";
                        var3_4 = "before delay " + extra;
                        var4_9 = false;
                        System.out.println((Object)var3_4);
                        var3_5 = this;
                        var4_9 = false;
                        var5_10 = false;
                        this.L$0 = extra;
                        this.L$1 = var3_5;
                        this.label = 1;
                        var5_11 = var3_5;
                        var6_12 = false;
                        var7_13 = new SafeContinuation(IntrinsicsKt.intercepted((Continuation)var5_11));
                        it = (Continuation)var7_13;
                        $i$a$-suspendCoroutine-AppKt$main$1$1 = false;
                        this.$context.element = it;
                        v0 = var7_13.getOrThrow();
                        if (v0 == IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED()) {
                            DebugProbesKt.probeCoroutineSuspended((Continuation)var3_5);
                        }
                        v1 = v0;
                        if (v0 == var10_2) {
                            return var10_2;
                        }
                        ** GOTO lbl33
                    }
                    case 1: {
                        var3_6 = this.L$1;
                        extra = (String)this.L$0;
                        ResultKt.throwOnFailure((Object)$result);
                        v1 = $result;
lbl33:
                        // 2 sources

                        var3_8 = "after suspend " + extra;
                        var4_9 = false;
                        System.out.println((Object)var3_8);
                        return Unit.INSTANCE;
                    }
                }
                throw new IllegalStateException("call to 'resume' before 'invoke' with coroutine");
            }
```

Comment: that is a great explanation

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin Coroutines, the `suspend` function is a keyword used to mark a function as a `coroutine`. A `coroutine` is a lightweight thread-like structure that allows for the sequential execution of asynchronous or long-running operations without blocking the main thread.

When a function is marked with suspend, it means that the function can suspend its execution at certain points without blocking the thread, allowing other coroutines to run. These suspensions typically occur when waiting for asynchronous operations to complete, such as network requests or disk I/O.
Here's an example of a function using the suspend keyword:

```
suspend fun fetchData(): String {
    delay(1000) // Simulating a delay for demonstration purposes [it also suspend function]
    return "Data fetched!"
}
```

what suspend function do ?

```
1- pause/resume 

2- save all variables (save the progress of function when function is pause and resume)
```

what you need to call suspend function ?

```
you need a coroutines scope to call suspend function or another suspend function
```

type couroutines scope

**1 - lifecycleScope -> (with activity) = aware activity lifecycle**

**2 - viewModelScope  -> (with viewModel) = aware viewModel lifecycle**

**3 - GlobalScope -> will work with application scope**

**4 - runBlocking -> (not recommended because make blocking thread)**

**5 - more...**

So who can i call suspend function using kotlin ?
you call launch it in the 5 thread

**1 - Main Thread -> using for UI**

**2 - IO Thread -> using for Input output**

**3- Deafult Thread**

**4 - Unconfined Thread**

**5 - custom Thread -> you created it **

to call suspend function 3 things

> ```
> first you need `builder` (Scope)
> ```

> ```
> second `Dispatchers` (for any thread you will work) [Optional]
> ```

> ```
> third `body of scope` you can call suspend here
> ```

let's take an example

```
fun main(){
   GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO/*[Optional]*/){
      // this is body 
      for(i in 1..10){
        Log.i("TEST", fetchData())   // open logcat to see the result           
      }
   }
}
```

when you finish the coroutine will go back to Main thread

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have a function named myFunction.

```
fun myFunction(){
Code block 1
Code block 2 //this one has a long running operation
Code block 3
Code block 4
}
```

Usually these  code blocks execute like block1, block2, block3, block4 . So code block 3 and 4 might execute  while code block 2 is still running. Because of that reason there can be problems. (screen might freeze, app might crash)

But if we make this function suspend

```
suspend fun MyFunction(){
Code block 1
Code block 2 //this one has a long running operation
Code block 3
Code block 4
}
```

Now, this function can get paused when code block 2(long running operation) starts executing and get resumed when it is done. Code block 3 and 4 will execute after that. So there will be no unexpected thread sharing issues.

Comment: How can blocks 3 and 4 get executed when block 2 is unfinished in the without-suspend function example?

Answer (score -1):

For anyone still wondering how do we actually suspend a suspend function, we use the suspendCoroutine function in the body of the suspend function .

```
    suspend fun foo() :Int
  {
    Log.d(TAG,"Starting suspension")
    return suspendCoroutine<Int> { num->

      val result = bar()
      Log.d(TAG,"Starting resumption")           
      num.resumeWith(Result.success(result))
    }

  }

fun bar():Int //this is a long runnning task
```

Comment: I don't know what you were trying to achieve by this code, but `suspendCoroutine` is mainly used with some legacy code with callbacks. What is the point of using `suspendCoroutine` here? It doesn't switch context to background thread, so it will block the thread in which the coroutine runs. If the coroutine uses `Dispatchers.Main` context, it will block the Main Thread.