# Does the suspend keyword in Kotlin do anything without coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin

My understanding is that Kotlin's coroutines are libraries, which leaves the only language-level feature of concurrency in Kotlin as the `suspend` keyword.

I'm still wrapping my head around coroutines in Kotlin, but I'm wondering if that may be overkill for my problem, which is updating a text view as soon as an `HttpsURLConnection` returns data. exception handling makes callbacks ugly enough that I want to avoid those if possible

does the suspend keyword simply mean that the runtime may suspend a function that takes a while to complete? or is suspension only enabled inside a coroutine? as a hypothetical, can I write

```
suspend fun getStringFromNetwork(): String {
  val request = URL("https:stackoverflow.com").openConnection()
  val result = readStream(request.inputStream)
  request.disconnect()
  return result
}

//and then elsewhere
foo()
val s = getStringFromNetwork()
bar(s)
baz()
```

and know that if `getStringFromNetwork` downloads 1 GB of data that `baz()` will be called in the meantime, while `bar(s)` waits for `s` to be populated by `getStringFromNetwork`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47871868/what-does-suspend-function-mean-in-kotlin-coroutine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "and then elsewhere" part calls `getStringFromNetwork()`, so it won't compile outside a `suspend` function (including `suspend` lambdas), and they can only be executed inside coroutines.

> that baz() will be called in the meantime, while bar(s) waits for s to be populated by getStringFromNetwork?

No, if you write it this way, `baz()` will only start executing after `bar(s)` returns. But of course `bar(s)` can start a new coroutine which will do the actual work.