# How to properly handle cancellation in coroutine's computation code?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Here is my understanding of cancellation in coroutine:

> If a parent coroutine is canceled, the children will stop too. If a
>   child coroutine throws Exception, the sibling and parent coroutine
>   will notice it and stop.
>
> Except for SupervisorJob, it will continue active even though one of
>   the child coroutines is stopped.

So, I write a code snippet to practice my understanding.

**Code Snippet 1**

```
fun main() {
    val parentScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())
    parentScope.launch {
        val childJob = launch {
            try {
                println("#1")
                Thread.sleep(1_000)
                println("#2")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("#3")
            }
        }
        println("#4")
        childJob.cancel()
    }
    Thread.sleep(2_000)
}
```

Here are two of my expectations:

Expectation 1:

```
#1 is called first because there's no blocking code between child and parent job.
#4 is called because `Thread.sleep` is blocking.
#3 is called because the childJob is cancelled, even though the coroutine is not finished.
```

Expectation 2:

```
#4 is called first because the parent coroutine start first.
#1 is called because even though the childJob is cancelled, there's time for #1 to be executed.
```

However, the actual output of code snippet 1 is:

```
#4
#1
#2
```

I read [coroutine docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html) again to find out that for computation code, we have to either use `yield` or check the coroutine state (`active`, `canceled`, `isCompleted`). Then I make the following adjustment:

**Code Snippet 2**

```
fun main() {
    val parentScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())
    parentScope.launch {
        val childJob = launch {
            try {
                println("#1")
                Thread.sleep(1_000)
                if (isActive) {
                    println("#2")
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("#3")
            }
        }
        println("#4")
        childJob.cancel()
    }
    Thread.sleep(2_000)
}
```

This time the output is:

```
#4
#1
```

Here are my questions:

1. In code snippet 1, how is #2 still executed after `childJob` is canceled?
2. In code snippet 1, why #3 is never executed even though `childJob` is called?
3. In code snippet 2, do we really need to use `yield` or checking coroutine state every time we want to execute a coroutine code? Because in my opinion, the code will be harder to read.
4. Is there something wrong my code snippet or my understanding of coroutine?

**Note:**
I don't want to use `GlobalScope.runBlocking` for the code snippet, because in the real project, we don't use `GlobalScope` anyway. I want to create an example as close as what a real project should be, using parent-child scoping with some lifecycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In code snippet 1, how is #2 still executed after childJob is
>   canceled?

Only suspending functions [are cancellable](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative). Replace `Thread.sleep(1_000)` with suspending [delay](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/delay.html) and it would be cancelled.

> In code snippet 1, why #3 is never executed even though childJob is
>   called?

It's because the coroutine wasn't cancelled. See the first question answer.

> In code snippet 2, do we really need to use yield or checking
>   coroutine state every time we want to execute a coroutine code?
>   Because in my opinion, the code will be harder to read.

No, you shouldn't. Every suspending function checks for cancellation of coroutine.

> Is there something wrong my code snippet or my understanding of
>   coroutine?

It's essential to understand suspending functions when you work with coroutines. [Coroutine Basics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#coroutine-basics) documentation section explains it pretty well. And may be the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47871868/4858777) would be useful.