# How to make asynchronous tasks and return value only when value is available? (the response is not empty)?

Tags: function, android-asynctask, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

I have a function which returns a List of Strings. This function requesting a response from the server. But firstly the function returns null, then a bit later returns a response with String. How to make it return the string from the beginning, avoid "empty response"?

```
 var array = listOf<String>()

    private fun getNetworkResponse(): List<String> {

        scope.launch {
            val list = api.getVideo().data
            val reply = list?.map { it?.url }
            array = reply as List<String>
            Log.d(MY_TAG, "array 1 $array ")
        }

        Log.d(MY_TAG, "array 2 $array ")
        return array
    }
```

So above function first return empty array, and late with response:

Log array 2 []

Log array 1 [https://..]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:
I use async suspend courutin. This function waits until the end of the task and returns the result.

```
suspend fun getNetworkResponse(): Array<String?> {
     scope.async {
                    ...
                    value = reply.toTypedArray()
                    Log.d(MY_TAG, "value 1 $reply ")

        }.await()
        Log.d(MY_TAG, "value 2 $value ")
        return value
    }
```

Log value 1 [http...]

Log value 2 []

Note: due to the function suspend!, to launch it I use runBlocking{}

```
runBlocking {
            getNetworkResponse()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason being that is that is not in the scope of coroutines. so it doesnt push either resume back it just go next next.....

> Log array 2 []

As Reason below with explain of Suspending function , it will push and resumed at a later time when the job done.
That why you see it log it being called after  Log array 2[].

> Log array 1 [https://..]

Since you tagged **kotlin-coroutines**, I assume you are using Retrofit for api call.

```
@GET("endpoint/video")
 suspend fun getVideo(): Response<List<Video>>
```

> **[Suspending functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47871868/what-does-the-suspend-function-mean-in-a-kotlin-coroutine)** are at the center of everything coroutines. A suspending function is simply a function that can be paused and
> resumed at a later time. They can execute a long running operation and
> wait for it to complete without blocking.

For suspend function you only call it from coroutines scope. as it said paused and resumed after they done with execute . It will return the values once it done.

Base on your function you don't need to return values

```
    var array = listOf<String>()
    private fun getNetworkResponse() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { // Background Thread
            val list = api.getVideo().data?.map { it?.url }
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                array = list
                // update UI on Main Thread
            }
        }

    }
```

or another way is make getNetworkResponse() as suspend with return List

Example :

```
 private suspend fun getNetworkResponse(): List<String> {
    val list = api.getVideo().data
    return list?.map { it?.url } ?? emptyList<String>()
}
```