# what does it really mean to block a thread?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin-coroutines

Given

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GlobalScope.launch {
        doNetworkCall()
        doNetworkCall2()
    }
}

suspend fun doNetworkCall() {
   delay(3000)
  Log.d("TRACE", "doNetworkCall1 in ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
}

suspend fun doNetworkCall2() {
  delay(3000)
  Log.d("TRACE", "doNetworkCall2 in ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
}
```

results in
sleep for 3 seconds, then print "doNetworkCall1 in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1"
sleep for 3 seconds, then pribnt "doNetworkCall2 in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1"

according to the javadoc for delay, "Delays a coroutine for a given amount of time without blocking the thread".

In my example I launch 1 coroutine.  This coroutine is delayed twice, first for 3 seconds before printing "doNetworkCall1...", and then before printing "doNetworkCall2...".  But we are in the same thread, worker-1, which is clearly blocked as these logs are printed sequentially.

Also, let's say there was a way for me to launch another coroutine after this one that operated on the same thread (thread 1).  The second coroutine would not wait for the first coroutine right?  In other words, while the lines WITHIN a coroutine body execute in sequential order, calls outside of different coroutines execute in an asynchronous fashion ie unordered

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  GlobalScope.launch {
    doNetworkCall()
    doNetworkCall2()
  }
  // pretend this runs in the same thread as coroutine 1, I just dont know how to do that
  GlobalScope.launch {
    doNetworkCall3()
    doNetworkCall4()
  }
}

suspend fun doNetworkCall() {
  delay(3000)
  Log.d("TRACE", "doNetworkCall1 in 
  ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
}

suspend fun doNetworkCall2() {
  delay(3000)
  Log.d("TRACE", "doNetworkCall2 in 
  ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
}
```

So doNetworkCall1() must execute before doNetworkCall2() starts, doNetworkCall3() must execute before doNetworkCall4() starts, but it is unknown if doNetworkCall1() or doNetworkCall3() runs first because coroutines do not block a thread, in this case thread 1.

Comment: Well you're `launch`ing only a single coroutine. Do two concurrent launches and you'll get concurrent delays.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you get it more or less right.

By saying the thread is blocked we mean it is occupied exclusively by its current task and can't be used for anything else. Usually, we use this term if the "task" is actually waiting for something, so the thread is not doing any real work, but it is still occupied fully and can't be utilized.

> But we are in the same thread, worker-1, which is clearly blocked as these logs are printed sequentially.

No, the thread is not blocked. Coroutine is "blocked", it waits in-place, but the underlying thread is not blocked, it is free to execute another coroutine while this one is waiting.

The easiest way to show the difference between blocking and suspending is by using a single thread and scheduling concurrent tasks on it. I used a similar example to yours, by applying coroutines and then more classic approach with a Java executor. Coroutines:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val dispatcher = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()

    GlobalScope.launch(dispatcher) {
        println("1 in ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        delay(1000)
        println("2 in ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }

    Thread.sleep(500)

    GlobalScope.launch(dispatcher) {
        println("3 in ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        delay(1000)
        println("4 in ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }
}
```

Output is: `1 3 2 4`, lines show every ~500ms, 1500ms in total.

Now executor, almost the same code:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

    executor.submit {
        println("1 in ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        println("2 in ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }

    Thread.sleep(500)

    executor.submit {
        println("3 in ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        println("4 in ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }
}
```

Output is: `1 2 3 4`, second task has to wait until the first finishes, so it takes 2000ms in total.

Conclusion: if using coroutines, even if single-threaded, we can reuse the thread for other coroutines, while we are delaying, waiting for I/O, or for another coroutine.

Comment: OK, I think your coroutines example is consistent with my understanding.  Lines in a coroutine run in order IF there is not another coroutine ON THE SAME THREAD.  Otherwise, execution of coroutines on the same thread can intersperse.  2 questions
1.Why is each line printed with 500ms in between if your thread is slept once for 500ms?
2.If I run your example the logs seem to indicate these coroutines run on separate threads instead of 1
1 in pool-1-thread-1
3 in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
2 in pool-1-thread-1
4 in DefaultDispatcher-worker-2

Comment: First job run at T+0, so `1` shows at T+0 and `2` at T+1000. Second job starts at T+500, so `3` shows at T+500 and `4` at T+1500. As a result, we see `1 3 2 4` at 0, 500, 1000 and 1500 accordingly. If using a Java executor it is `1 2 3 4` at 0, 1000, 1000 and 2000 accordingly.

Comment: 2. Did you specify a dispatcher as in my example? You clearly used the default dispatcher and in my example I used another one, based on a single-thread executor.

Comment: Also, I think you focus too much on what a thread is doing. Instead, you should think about what a coroutine is doing and leave threads for the coroutine machinery. What you said above is not entirely correct: execution of a coroutine is always sequential, no matter if we run another coroutine or not. Also, even if we launched only a single coroutine, we don't know which thread will pick it up after a `delay()`. In your example it was picked by the same thread as before `delay()`, but it could be really any other thread.

Comment: Sorry I used the wrong dispatcher earlier.  Is our execution order

1. 1 prints
2. START co 1's delay(1000)
3. Thread.sleep(500)
4. co 1 suspends for coroutine 2 to print 3
5. START co 2's delay(1000)
6. Return to co 1 to resume delay from step 2, w/500ms left
7. print 2
8. in co 2 delay w/500ms left
9. print 4

as execution switched between co 1 and 2 my assertion was you cant read it in order ie lines in co 1 must start before lines in co 2 because if that were the case it would print 1 2 3 4.

Comment: This is more or less correct, but I feel you assume a coroutine need another coroutine to suspend/resume. "co 1 suspends for coroutine 2 to print 3" - co 1 suspends no matter if there is another coroutine or not. It doesn't even know about it. "Return to co 1 to resume delay from step 2, w/500ms left" - it doesn't resume to delay - it resumes after the delay.

Comment: We can't be 100% precise on the order of execution here as we do concurrent processing, but I would say: 1. Main thread launches co 1. 2. Main thread starts to sleep for 500ms. 3. Co 1 starts, prints `1` and starts waiting for 1000ms. 4. Main thread resumes and launches co 2. 5. Co 2 starts, prints `3` and starts waiting for 1000ms. 6. Co 1 resumes after waiting, prints `2` and completes. 7. Co 2 resumes after waiting, prints `4` and completes.

Comment: Thank you for showing how to run coroutines on a single, specified thread.

Answer (score 3):

> But we are in the same thread, worker-1, which is clearly blocked as these logs are printed sequentially.

Coroutines violate your trained intuition in the following way: when your code seems to call `delay(3000)` and wait for it to complete, in reality the compiled code *returns* from `delay()` with a special result value `COROUTINE_SUSPENDED`, and all the calling functions return it as well, until the innermost calling function that is not suspendable (in your case `launch`). The internals of this function will attach the special `Continuation` object (which appears as a hidden argument to all suspendable functions) to a `Runnable` and pass it to a scheduled task executor in charge of the thread. The executor will run the task after 3000 ms.

The precise technical details are a bit different when the thread in question is the GUI thread, but nothing essential changes.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48112934/1103872) another answer with code that should help expose a few aspects of this story.

Comment: This answer is helpful, but it doesn't address the title question ...

Comment: My conclusion was that this is the essence of OP's confusion. It's evident in what they point out as "clearly blocking the thread". This explains the seeming paradox of a coroutine being blocked without blocking its thread.